# How to Use `predict()` without errors in a model when you have missing data?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, na, missing-data, glm

I have a pretty simply logistic regression model based solely on two categorical predictors in `Race` and `Sex`. Firstly, since I have some missing values, to make sure all the missing data comes in as `NA`, I import the data frame using the following:

```
> mydata <- read.csv("~/Desktop/R/mydata.csv", sep=",", strip.white = TRUE,
+                    na.strings= c("999", "NA", " ", ""))
```

Here's the summary of the predictors to see how many `NA`s there are:

```
> # Define variables 
> 
> Y <- cbind(Support)
> X <- cbind(Race, Sex)
>
> summary(X) 
      Race               Sex          
 Min.   :1.000000   Min.   :1.000000  
 1st Qu.:1.000000   1st Qu.:1.000000  
 Median :2.000000   Median :1.000000  
 Mean   :1.608696   Mean   :1.318245  
 3rd Qu.:2.000000   3rd Qu.:2.000000  
 Max.   :3.000000   Max.   :3.000000  
 NA's   :420        NA's   :42
```

The model seems to do what it's supposed to with no problems due to the missing values:

```
> # Logit model coefficients 
> 
> logit <- glm(Y ~ X, family=binomial (link = "logit")) 
> 
> summary(logit) 

Call:
glm(formula = Y ~ X, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-2.0826825  -1.0911146   0.6473451   1.0190080   1.7457212  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.3457629  0.2884629  4.66529 3.0818e-06 ***
XRace       -1.0716191  0.1339177 -8.00207 1.2235e-15 ***
XSex         0.5910812  0.1420270  4.16175 3.1581e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1434.5361  on 1057  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1347.5684  on 1055  degrees of freedom
  (420 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 1353.5684

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

**Question 1:** When I don't have any `NA`s, this code seems to work well. But I get an error message whenever there are missing values. Is there a way to still see how many correctly predicted values I have, regardless of missing data or not?

```
> table(true = Y, pred = round(fitted(logit))) 
Error in table(true = Y, pred = round(fitted(logit))) : 
all arguments must have the same length
```

Edit: After adding `na.action = na.exclude` to the model definition, the table now works perfectly:

```
        pred 

true   0    1

  0   259  178 

  1   208  413
```

Something that does still work, regardless of missing data, is loading the predictions onto the original data frame when I use this code. It correctly adds a 'pred' column at the end of the data frame with each row's probability (and simply adds an `NA` instead if one of the predictors does not exist):

```
> predictions = cbind(mydata, pred = predict(logit, newdata = mydata, type = "response"))
> write.csv(predictions, "~/Desktop/R/predictions.csv", row.names = F)
```

**Question 2:** However, when I try to predict into a new data frame -- even though it has the same variables of interest -- it seems like something about the missing values cause an error message as well. Is there code to get around this, or am I doing something incorrectly?

```
> newpredictions = cbind(newdata, pred = predict(logit, newdata = newdata, type = "response"))
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1475, 1478
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 1475 rows but variables found have 1478 rows
```

As you can see above, the number of rows in `mydata` is 1,478 and the number of rows in `newdata` is 1,475.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Btw, you;'re making a mistake in reading in and treating `Race` as numeric instead of factor: you can see you get one linear coefficient for Race, instead of two/three separate coefficients for each contrast level (`Race1, Race.2, Race.3`). You need to take `as.factor(Race)`

Comment: *"Something that does still work, regardless of missing data, is loading the predictions onto the original data frame when I use this code."* Beware of vector recycling in R with different-length vectors; make sure the rows correspond to what you think they do. Really, you should never have NAs in either input or output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have missing data, `NA`s, R will strip these when the modelling functions does `formula` -> `model.frame` -> `model.matrix()` etc., because the default in all these functions is to have `na.action = na.omit`. In other words, rows with `NA`s are deleted before the actual computations are performed. This deletion propagates through to the fitted values, residuals etc that are accessed from the model object

Realising this is an issue, R has other `na.action` functions, including `na.exclude()`. Hence if you add

```
na.action = na.exclude
```

to your call to `glm()`, `fitted()`, `resid()`, etc would return as many fitted values as you have rows in your put data.

You do seem to be going about modelling in a peculiar way. Why are you creating `X` and `Y`, presumably from your `mydata` object? It would be **far** better to do

```
mod <- glm(Support ~ Race + Sex, data = mydata family = binomial,
           na.action = na.exclude)
```

where now instead of the anonymous `X` and `Y` we have variables that mean something, and you haven't had to create duplicate data.

Comment: Thanks so much! Three things: (1) Adding `na.action = na.exclude` totally solved my first question, so now my table works perfectly. I'll edit my question above to reflect that. (2) Though it doesn't fix my second question outright for predicting `newdata`. Is that because the `newdata` data frame has `NA`s still? (3) Finally, I use generic `X` and `Y` with `mydata`, etc., so I can easily type in new variables at the top of my script and have everything easily change below. Should I avoid this? Thanks again!

Comment: It's difficult to tell until you edit the question and show what is failing. As for 3) your approach is going to cause more problems than it is worth - you will have to work against a lot of R's modelling conveniences, so good luck to you... in other words, avoid this. It also sounds a lot like data dredging.

Comment: I think 2) arises because you don't have variables named `X` in `newdata`. Is this the case?

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right. Exactly what you were just warning me about coming back to bite me. Seems to work now -- thanks a lot!